# Github and CSS Assist

Tags: html, css, github

I've read others having this problem but can't seem to find a solution to fix my issue. I initially upload a simple html site (web dev bootcamp thing) which worked fine. Now I'm trying to add my css style sheet (external) and it doesn't work. When I pull it up locally it works fine. 
Github Site: https://jessicaschmitt104.github.io/cv/

I've tried several tips on StackOverflow and the Github help pages with no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jessica's Personal Site</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>
```

I'm pretty new at this, so any is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think your CSS is blank

Comment: @JSchmitt there is no style.css in your repository, upload it to your repository and try

Answer (score 0):

try putting a `./` in front of the `css/styles.css`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this!.